# WBF compatible device

Tags: sdk, fingerprint

i'm planning to use WBF in my graduation project , i would like to know the finger print devices which are compatible with it , and also is it really preferred solution to use wbf or do you prefer any other frame work for finger print reading

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for now, WBF is the only framevork for fingerprint readers.
Look Validity Sensors for supported readers.